# How to execute "Set-ProcessMitigation -Name myapplication.exe -Enable PreferSystem32" PowerShell command from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I am trying to execute a PowerShell command `Set-ProcessMitigation -Name myapplication.exe -Enable PreferSystem32` from my **WPF** application. But the PowerShell window just opens and then closes, without the script being executed.

The code

**C# file MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public void Run_scripts()
    {
        var ps1File = @"-NoExit C:\pwsh.ps1";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -file \"{ps1File}\""
            UseShellExecute = true
            RedirectStandardOutput = true               
        };

        try
        {                
            var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);                             
            MessageBox.Show("Powershell Command Executed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

**PowerShell script pwsh.ps1**

```
Write-Output "power shell executed";
Set-ProcessMitigation -Name Wireless@SGx.exe -Enable PreferSystem32;
```

Comment: Try moving `-NoExit` from your ps1File variable to before `-File` in the Arguments variable

Comment: @Daniel I have moved -NoExit before -File,  

Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -NoExit -file \"{ps1File}\"" 

But still it is not working

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: `UseShellExecute` needs to be set to `false` when redirect is set to true or an exception is thrown and your script is not executed.